# Google Workspace Drive - creating documents issue "Something went wrong"

Tags: google-chrome, google-workspace

I have a problem with my new Google Workspace. When I am creating a new document or sheet, there is always only message "Something went wrong. Reload":

[image]

After reload, there is next page with message:
[image]

Under the same Chrome browser I am using two profiles, personal and business.
In personal Drive, everything works properly. The problem is only with Google Workspace profile.

I already tried to clean all Chrome data (history, cookies, setting...) but nothing solve this issue.

Do you have any idea where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after about 20 hours Google Drive under workspace starts work poperly.
I seems that, there was some issue on some Google servers.